# Error in app script code that will not function due to forEach

Tags: google-apps-script

How do you get this to work with this line below as it does not run?

I am trying to use this on a google form

Results required

"On form Submit" - I want to create a subfolder in my main folder (named based on a field within the form)

I want the uploaded files to go into the created subfolder

Error code

**7:14:19 AM Error

/TypeError: itemResponses[1].getResponse(...).forEach is not a function
onFormSubmit @ Code.gs:16/**

**itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder)); }**

Full code below

```
function onFormSubmit(e) {
const folderId = "###";  // Please set top folder ID of the destination 
folders.
const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
const formResponses = form.getResponses();
const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length- 
1].getItemResponses();

Utilities.sleep(3000); // This line might not be required.

// Prepare the folder.
const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
const folderName = itemResponses[3].getResponse();
const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder : 
destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

// Move files to the folder.
itemResponses[1].getResponse().forEach(id => 
DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```

Comment: Without seeing the corresponding form its hard to tell what the issue may be. Can you provide the form? The issue seems to be that `itemResponses[1].getResponse()` does not return a list.

Answer (score 0):

[getFoldersByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder#getfoldersbynamename) return

> FolderIterator — a collection of all folders that are children of the
> current folder and have the given name.

You need to get one of the collection folders with [next()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder-iterator#next).

The "if" should look like this:

```
const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I was just having this problem and found that my item response number was not on the correct question to grab the file upload. It's important to remember that the responses start with 0 instead of 1 like we might expect.
I resolved the issue by setting each response I was calling to a constant, then using Logger.log() on each and adjusting until the logs output the correct response.
(My situation is a little more complex with three separate file uploads and two different destinations)
But here's essentially what I did:

```js
function onFormSubmit(e) {
  const folderId = "###"; // ID of the destination folder
  const form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  const formResponses = form.getResponses();
  const itemResponses = formResponses[formResponses.length - 1].getItemResponses();

  // Prepare the folder.
  const destFolder = DriveApp.getFolderById(folderId);
  const folderName = itemResponses[3].getResponse();

  Logger.log(folderName)

  const subFolder = destFolder.getFoldersByName(folderName);
  const folder = subFolder.hasNext() ? subFolder.next() : destFolder.createFolder(folderName);

  // Move files to the folder.
  const responseOne = itemResponses[1].getResponse()

  Logger.log(responseOne)

  responseOne.forEach(id => DriveApp.getFileById(id).moveTo(folder));
}
```